# Send mail when my grant status has been changed

Tags: civirules, civigrant

I am try to send mail when grant status has been changed. For this I am using CiviRules . I create a rule Trigger(Grant is changed). Then I try to add my status condtion but not find it. Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CiviRules is a work in progress. Maybe this condition is not implemented yet. But you can do it yourself. The following manual describes how:

https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-condition/